Reasons for polygamy amongst the Dvija
As Medhatithi's Manubhashya states, "This however is not right; because in regard to men there is a distinct sanction—(a) ‘Those who act through mere lust, etc.,’ (b) ‘the barren wife shall be superseded in the eighth year,’ and so forth; while there is no such sanction in the case of women. There is another text also which is indicative of the same fact—‘There are several wives for one man, but not several husbands for a woman at the same time."
1.) Is "a)" allowing a man to do polygamy for lust or contrasting lusty and non-lusty people in regards to polygamy?
2.) What are the social and religious reasons for allowing polygamy to occur?

Polygamy was the norm throughout Asia. The modern concept of having one wife at a time is derived of the Tanakh & became considered as the quote-unquote 'global' standard due to colonialism.

@অনু It being the norm and it's practice were two different things entirely.

All I wanna know is why.


Polygamy is justified in some religious contexts to ensure the birth of virtuous offspring who contribute positively to society.
Marriages are encouraged to be between individuals of good character and compatible traits to foster harmonious relationships and nurture good qualities in descendants.
There's an analogy where men are seen as carriers of hereditary traits ("seed"), and women as nurturers ("soil"), emphasizing compatibility for healthy progeny.
Polygamy historically favored leaders and individuals of high social status to propagate noble lineages, while restrictions often applied to lower social strata.
Second marriages were permitted primarily to ensure offspring or male heirs, especially if the first wife was unable to conceive or bear a male child.
Polygamous unions were sometimes politically motivated, serving to forge alliances or strengthen diplomatic ties between rulers or nations.
In some scriptures, marriage rules varied by caste, allowing Brahmins (seers) and Kshatriyas (kings) broader marriage choices compared to boys from other castes. In certain traditional Hindu scriptures and societal norms, there exists a practice where boys from higher caste backgrounds, such as Brahmins, Kshatriyas, and Vaisyas, are allowed to marry girls from either the same caste or a lower caste. However, the reverse—girls from higher castes marrying boys from lower castes—is generally not permitted. This asymmetry stems from deep-rooted caste-based hierarchies and notions of purity and pollution within Hindu society. It reflects historical preferences to maintain purity in higher castes while allowing for some flexibility in marriages involving lower castes.


Add some supporting information please.
